# Image Rotation not woring properly

Tags: android, matrix, imageview

I am displaying an image using matrix.but it rotate around the circle,seems like(obviously) co-ordinates changes every time.i want to rotate it at the center.here is my code.

```
        Matrix m = new Matrix();
        RectF r = new RectF(0, 0, im.getWidth(), im.getHeight());
        RectF rf = new RectF(0, 0, circleWidth, circleHeight);

        m.setRectToRect(r, rf, Matrix.ScaleToFit.CENTER);
         //185 is the half of imagesize.

        m.postRotate(angle, 185, 185);
        im.setImageMatrix(m);

        im.setScaleType(ScaleType.MATRIX);
        im.invalidate();
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you trying to get an image to spin around its centre? I have some old code that does that, but I'm  a bit rusty on the details.

The only difference I can see between my working code and yours, is that I use the method `ImageView.getImageMatrix()` instead of creating a `new Matrix()`.

So my code looks more like this:

```
    // avgAngle is the angle of rotation
    // imageView is my ImageView containing the image to rotate

    int halfHeight = imageView.getHeight() / 2;
    int halfWidth = imageView.getWidth() / 2;

    // rotate image
    Matrix m = imageView.getImageMatrix();
    m.postRotate(avgAngle, halfWidth, halfHeight);
    imageView.postInvalidate();
```

I call this code from an animation thread - hence the use of `postInvalidate()` to force it to happen on the main thread.

---

For what its worth, here is the full code (its not very good) - maybe it will help:

```
private Runnable Spinnamation = new Runnable()
{
    public void run()
    {
        // animating is a global boolean flag for the whole Activity
        // card is my ImageView
        // getAverageAngle() method gives the rotation per second

        animating = true;
        float avgAngle = getAverageAngle();
        int halfHeight = card.getHeight() / 2;
        int halfWidth = card.getWidth() / 2;

        long now = new Date().getTime();
        while ((now + 3000) > (new Date().getTime()))
        {
            // rotate image
            Matrix rotateMatrix = card.getImageMatrix();
            rotateMatrix.postRotate(avgAngle, halfWidth, halfHeight);
            card.postInvalidate();

            try
            {
                Thread.sleep(30);
            }
            catch (InterruptedException e)
            {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

        animating = false;
    }
};
```

I call it simply from this method:

```
/**
 * Applies a spinning animation to the whole view.
 */
private void startSpinnamation()
{
    if (!animating)
    {
        new Thread(Spinnamation).start();
    }
}
```

Comment: :still same problem.doesn't matter i take imageView.getMatrix() or new Matrix();

Answer (score 0):

Try this. It will be useful for you

```
int angle = 0;

            if (orientation == ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_ROTATE_90) {
                angle = 90;
            } else if (orientation == ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_ROTATE_180) {
                angle = 180;
            } else if (orientation == ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_ROTATE_270) {
                angle = 270;
            }

            Matrix mat = new Matrix();
            mat.postRotate(angle);
```